# Function Score On Nested Object

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this index `blog` with the following `settings` and `mappings`.

```
PUT /blog
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": "1"
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "post": {
      "_all": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "content": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "visitor": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "id": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "last_visit": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to rank my posts based on relevancy and visitor's last visit. I tried this query without success. It seems like the gauss function cannot get the value of `visitor`'s `last_visit`. How to get this worked?

```
POST /blog/post/_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "functions": [
        {
          "gauss": {
            "visitor.last_visit": {
              "origin": "now/d",
              "offset": "3d",
              "scale": "4d",
              "decay": 0.5
            }
          },
          "filter": {
            "nested": {
              "path": "visitor",
              "query": {
                "term": {
                  "visitor.id": "1"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: are you getting an error when running this query? or it just doesn't produce the results you hoped it would?

Comment: @chester89 I didn't get any error. When I read the explanation, it does not use `visitor`'s `last_visit`, it always use `0.0`. I'm suspicious that it could not get the value.

Comment: I suggest you try your query on a non-nested field first. if it works, may be the problem is with nested field

Comment: also take a look at https://discuss.elastic.co/t/nested-value-on-function-score/29935/3

Answer (score 1):

Here is a query with a match for a name that uses a nested object that I had for a particular use case. I didn't use any date fields, but as I said, it does use a nested object.  I used relevancy of distance along with a text match, so it's similar.

I used the answer from this question to structure my query as it matched what I was trying to do.  [Scoring documents by text match and distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38015356/scoring-documents-by-both-textual-match-and-distance-to-a-point)

```
GET dev_search_core_data/_search?size=200
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "NAME": "Amy Smith"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "function_score": {
                  "query": {
                    "nested": {
                      "path": "LOCATION",
                      "query": {
                        "term": {
                          "LOCATION.SOME_IND": {
                            "value": true
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "functions": [
                    {
                      "gauss": {
                        "LOCATION.COORDINATES": {
                          "origin": "-118.309, 34.041",
                          "scale": "50km",
                          "offset": "10km",
                          "decay": 0.5
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I think the problem is with the structure of your query. I always run this command first to validate my queries if I'm having any problems to eliminate any syntax issues.

```
GET dev_search_core_data/_validate/query?explain
```

This was the result:

```
{
   "valid": true,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "explanations": [
      {
         "index": "dev_search_core_data_b",
         "valid": true,
         "explanation": "filtered((NAME:amy NAME:smith) (+function score (ToParentBlockJoinQuery (filtered(LOCATION.SOME_IND:true)->random_access(_type:_LOCATION)),function=org.elasticsearch.index.query.functionscore.DecayFunctionParser$GeoFieldDataScoreFunction@274227b9)))->cache(org.elasticsearch.index.search.nested.NonNestedDocsFilter@1012ada6)"
      }
   ]
}
```

I also looked at the docs for an in-depth explanation of how the [function score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) worked.  You don't mention your version, but I'm using ES 1.6.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think your query is wrong. The `function_score` should be inside the nested query for the purpose of accessing the nested field, like [this post](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/nested-value-on-function-score/29935/2?u=puppylpg).